# XPath: select all A nodes and all B nodes that are not inside an A node

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath

Is the following possible in one XPath expression (see sample below):

Select all **(span tags of class msg)** AND all **((img tags that have a non-empty alt attribute)** AND **(are NOT located inside a span tag of class msg))**

Simplified sample:

```
<span class="msg">Message text A</span>
<img alt="" />
<span class="msg">Message text B <img alt="text A" /></span>
<span class="err">Error text C <img alt="text B" /></span>
<img alt="text C" />
<span class="err">Error text D</span>
```

The resulting node set should contain:

```
<span class="msg">Message text A</span>
<span class="msg">Message text B <img alt="text A" /></span>
<img alt="text B" />    
<img alt="text C" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not tested, but something like?

```
//span[@class='msg'] | //img[@alt!='' and not(ancestor::span[@class='msg'])]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect! 
I removed the first "not(ancestor::..." since the material can not contain msg span inside msg spans.
It saved two iterations through the same data, thus speeding up things.

Comment: OK - I miscounted some brackets ;-p